# Is $(\mathbb{Z_4},+) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z_5^{*}},\cdot), n\bmod 4 \mapsto n \bmod 5 $ a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

For the following relation

$(\mathbb{Z_4},+) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z_5^{*}},\cdot), n\bmod 4 \mapsto n \bmod 5  $

Determine if it is well-defined and an homomorphism

So I think it is not well-defined because $6\equiv 2 \text{ ( mod 4)}$, but $6\not \equiv 2 \text{ ( mod 5)}$, then it can't be a homomorphism either.

What do you think?

Comment: what about $[0]_4$ which is being map to $[0]_5$ but  $[0]_5 \notin \mathbb{Z}_5^*$, so it is not even well-defined as a mapping

Comment: @Peter Yes, they are isomorphic, but in no way defined by the map above.

Comment: @Bach Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. Nevertheless, there  exist isomorphisms between these groups, bu they're defined through generators of the group $\mathbf Z^\times$, which are $2$ and $3$, say via $2$:
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z&\longrightarrow(\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z)^\times\\
k\bmod4&\longmapsto 2^{k\bmod 4}\bmod 5
\end{align}

Comment: I think there is a typo here  :it is$\mathbf Z/\mathbf 4Z$ instead of $\mathbf Z/\mathbf Z$

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: Yes – should have checked. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: $\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z = \mathbf Z_4$ isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I use the standard notation, because there may be some confusion with the $p$-adic numbers when the modulus is prime, and also with the ring of fractions $\mathbf Z_{(n)}$.

Comment: If instead $(\mathbb{Z_5^{*}},\cdot)$ I take $(\mathbb{Z_5^{*}},+)$, are still isomorphic?

Comment: No, $\mathbf Z_5^\times$ is not an additive group (1+4 is not in the set, for instance).